# Magento2 commands

Tags: magento2

Do I need to run upgrade , compile and deploy commands on both development and production mode ?
Which commands are required if I only make changes to CSS and JS.
Thanks

Comment: After the update of css and js no need to run commands....just clear your browser  cache or use private browsing to view changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in developer mode you have no need to run any command but if you are in Production Model you have to run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` command to change JS And CSS Changes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- In your case, you just need to run **`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`** under your magento root folder. If your website is multilingual, don't forget to add various languages after this command.

  Ref: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html